# Kubernetes, Running two redis pods in the same cluster results in issues, running one of each on its own runs flawlessly

Tags: kubernetes, redis

Within my Kubernetes cluster, I manage four deployments:

- Laravel Queue Workers:   Labelled as laravel-kube-worker.
- Django Queue Workers:    Labelled as django-kube-worker.
- Laravel Redis Instance:  Labelled as laravel-kube-worker-redis.
- Django Redis Instance:   Labelled as django-kube-worker-redis.

I aim to connect the Laravel worker pods to its corresponding Redis instance to process the queued jobs stored there. Similarly, I'm attempting to do the same for the Django queue worker pods and their Redis counterpart.

Individually, both Laravel and Django deployments work perfectly. Laravel fills and processes its queue seamlessly, and so does Django. However, an issue arises when both sets of deployments run concurrently: the worker pods intermittently fail to connect to their respective Redis pods. This inconsistency is puzzling.

An example of me occasionally establishing a connection successfully, but it's not consistent or reliable. (In a time span of around 15 seconds).
[image]

I've also noticed no conflicting behaviors between the two Redis configurations. Below are the configuration files for the Laravel Redis deployment. Anything enclosed in ((....)) represents equivalent configurations for the Django Redis deployment.

Laravel redis deployment.yml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: laravel-kube-worker-redis  (( django-kube-worker-redis ))
  labels:
    tier: backend
    layer: redis
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 6379  (( 6380 ))
      targetPort: 6379  (( 6380 ))
      nodePort: 32379  (( 32380 ))
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    tier: backend
    layer: redis
  type: NodePort
```

Laravel redis persisten-volume-claim.yml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: laravel-kube-worker-redis  (( django-kube-worker-redis ))
spec:
  storageClassName: do-block-storage 
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Laravel redis statefulset.yml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: laravel-kube-worker-redis  (( django-kube-worker-redis ))
  labels:
    tier: backend
    layer: redis
spec:
  serviceName: laravel-kube-worker-redis  (( django-kube-worker-redis ))
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: backend
      layer: redis
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: backend
        layer: redis
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis:alpine
          command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes", "--bind", "0.0.0.0"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379  (( 6380 ))
              name: web
          volumeMounts:
            - name: redis-aof
              mountPath: /data
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "1048Mi" # Set the minimum memory request
            limits:
              memory: "4096Mi" # Set the maximum memory limit
      volumes:
        - name: redis-aof
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: laravel-kube-worker-redis  (( django-kube-worker-redis ))
```

It's maybe worth noting that all labels in the Django Redis equivalent have different key: values.

I also want to point out that for connectivity, inside the Laravel worker pods, I utilize laravel-kube-worker-redis:6379 to connect to the Redis environment.

Furthermore, upon inspecting the pods, services, and statefulsets statuses, everything seems in order. There are no forced restarts for the Redis pods, and all configurations match what's described in my examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
....

  # HERE IS YOUR PROBLEM
  selector:
    tier: backend
    layer: redis
  type: NodePort
```

Both of your Services are routing to *both* Redis deployments. A Service uses the labels on Pods to determine whether it should route to them. You are starting both redis deployments with the same labels and also configuring each Service with the same selector...

In short you need:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: laravel-kube-worker-redis
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
      nodePort: 32379
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    tier: backend
    layer: laravel-redis # more specific!
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: laravel-kube-worker-redis
  labels:
    tier: backend
    layer: laravel-redis # more specific!
spec:
  serviceName: laravel-kube-worker-redis
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: backend
      layer: laravel-redis # more specific!
```

See also https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/ for more context

Comment: This indeed solved my issue! Although, I still find connection inconsistency weird. Like why let me connect like 50% of the time instead of just always refusing my connection since these labels were coinflicting with eachother. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What would there be to refuse though? There is no conflict as far as Kubernetes is concerned. The labels essentially just say "view this Pod as a valid target for traffic coming to this Service". The Service will then use a simple routing algorithm (round-robin by default if I remember correctly) to forward all requests. So by definition 50% of calls will go to what you view as the "right" redis instance and the other 50% will go to the "wrong" one.